# Rails 4: not showing image when tab changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So the images show when the site loads, but when i navigate to another tab and then come back to the first tab, the images are not showing. Then i have to refresh the site for the image to show. 
I have tried to find the answer, but seems it is a very simple thing that i have overlooked.

Note: I am using a JavaScript background slider to show the images.
**index.html.erb:**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "home" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "index" %>
<div id="background_cycler" >
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#background_cycler').hide();
</script>

<img class="active" src="/assets/back/back2.jpg" alt=""/>
<img src="/assets/back/back2.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="/assets/back/back4.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="/assets/back/back5.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: I found the answer thank's to this post: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links    I had to load the JavaScript file first:     $(window).on('page:load', function(){
  ...code
    })